# How do I explain the output of this simple C code?

Tags: c, printf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i=10;
printf("%d",printf("%d",i));
return(0);
}
```

Output in Turbo C

> 102

I am a beginner. So can you explain how this code works?

Comment: What does the man page for `printf` say about its return value? [Please RTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM).

Comment: If you insert a `newline` it might be clearer. `printf("\n%d",printf("%d",i));`

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for [`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) states that it will return an integer that represents the number of characters written to the output stream.

That means you can use the return value of `printf` to satisfy a `%d` format specifier in another call to `printf`, and the second (outer) call will print out the number of characters written in the first call.

`i` is equal to `10`, so the first call to `printf` outputs the number `10` and returns `2` (number of characters in the string `"10"`), which is passed to the second call to `printf`, which prints `2`, giving you the final output `102`.

Comment: @Ricky you're welcome; once you've found a satisfactory answer to your question you can mark it as accepted by clicking the check box under the voting icons.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take apart the top level statement that produces the output:

```
printf("%d",printf("%d",i));
```

- We have a function call of `printf` at the top level, passing two arguments to the function
- The first argument of the top-level `printf` is the format string `"%d"`
- The second argument of the top-level `printf` is the result of invoking `printf("%d",i)`

The argument of top-level `printf`, i.e. `printf("%d",i)`, needs to be evaluated prior to making the call. The expression has a value, and a side effect. The side effect is printing `"10"` to the output, and the value is the number of characters printed, i.e. `2`.

Since the arguments are evaluated prior to making a call, the `printf("%d",i)` is invoked first, producing the output `10`. Now the top-level `printf` is invoked, and it produces the output `2`, completing the `"102"` sequence that you see.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1

> The `fprintf` function returns the number of characters transmitted, or a negative value
>   if an output or encoding error occurred.

In your case, the inner `printf()` call is the argument to the outer `printf()`, so the inner function call will be executed, as per the rule of function parameter evaluation.

So, in your case, first the inner `printf()` executes, printing the value of `i`, i.e., `10` (2 characters) and the return value of the `printf()` call is used as the argument to the `%d` format specifier in outer `printf()`, printing `2`.

As there is no visual separator present, you see the outputs adjacent to each other, appearing as `102`.

Comment: but why is the ouput : 102 ??

Answer (score 0):

printf() is a C function. It returns an int value equal to the number of bytes it prints.

In your case, the INNER printf printed "10", so it wrote 2 bytes and will return 2.

The OUTER printf will therefore print "2".

Final result: "102" ("10" of the INNER followed by "2" of the OUTER).